# Configure Firebase Hosting behavior with Rewrite Rules in firebase.json for (yourdomain.com/username)

Tags: javascript, firebase, url-rewriting

I am trying to make a web app in which user can signup, login and update their profile. So far it is done using Firebase and hosted all files on Firebase Hosting.

As of now my page URL looks like

```
mydomain.com/user/index.html?user=username
```

but when I enter

```
mydomain.com/username
```

It should behave same. What should be the rules?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish.  Firebase Auth is not very helpful unless users actually go through the sign-in process to verify their identity.

Comment: Firebase has a free support, you can raise your issue there [1].

[1] https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact?authuser=0